# trouble running basic test(unknown attribute error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am trying to run a basic test in minitest but getting the following error:

Error:
CategoryTest#test_category_should_be_valid:
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for Category.
    test/models/category_test.rb:5:in `setup'

but the model exists and the table and row exists in the database.

```
require 'test_helper'

class CategoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
def setup
    @category = Category.new(name: "sports")
end

test "category should be valid" do
    assert @category.valid?
end
end
```

and this is the migration table:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def change
create_table :categories do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

Comment: What does your `db/schema.rb` file say about `categories`?

Comment: @Phil,  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Comment: sorry about the format, but the attribute exists in the db so im not sure why im getting the unknown attribute error

Comment: If you run `bin/rails console`, you will probably get the `development` environment. Try your `.new()` call there. Another tip is to look at `Category.columns_hash.keys` and see if your `name` is in there.

Comment: when i run Category.columns_hash.keys i get ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"]. so its there. i can also create a new category with .new and the name attribute and it works. i thought maybe theres something wrong with the test

Comment: Run `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails console` and try the same experiments there. Rails often has an issue where the development database is not cloned into the test database.

Comment: Have you permitted name in controller? show contents of your controller

Answer (score 3):

Your testing database is possibly not up-to-date with your current db schema.  To update your test db, run

```
rails db:test:prepare
```